# Yellow dandelion-like flowers emerging from beach in early spring

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

What are these yellow-flowered plants?

[image]

- The yellow flowers look similar to dandelions, but the stalks are much thicker.
- No leaves yet, just flowers.
- March 30, 2024. Unusually warm winter this year.
- Lake Ontario beach. 50ft from the lake. 5ft from grassy embankment. Port Hope, Ontario.
- Flowering at the same time as snowdrops and Cornus mas in my garden in a nearby town.

Answer (score 5):

Not certain, but it looks pretty well like it could be Tussilago farfara (colt's foot or coltsfoot). It's a common invasive plant in your area.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussilago

https://www.fs.usda.gov/database/feis/plants/forb/tusfar/all.html

Comment: this plant deserves a longer answer with more details,like it is one of the first plants to flower in spring and it is able to increase it`s internal temperature to well above ambient temperature,it makes the flower survive even when there is frost during the nights in spring.

Comment: Tussilago/colt's foot is a fascinating plant, and I'm glad you identified it properly. I was unaware of its invasiveness. I was glad to see a patch on my property years ago and sad to see it disappear over the years. (Glad because at the time, I was interested in medieval herbal medicine. Tussilago is one that actually worked. Alas, it's a carcinogen, too.)

Comment: @trondhansen - More is nice, but the OP asked for ID. They can learn more by looking at the links, or if you like, you can post a more informative answer.